# Without using xml file configuration how can i use @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy?

Tags: java, spring-annotations

Now based on this link http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/ i done but in that example they using xml files so please help me to do using spring annotation or other way thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how you create your bean (XML, annotation, @Configuration class). As long
as you have the `<context:annotation-config />` it should work.

If you use `@Configuration` class you should add this annotation as well to the base configuration class `@EnableWebMvc`

They even mention adding it in the tutorial you referred to.

Comment: yeah you are right Avi. But for standalone java project with spring means is there any way to handle it???

Comment: @SujeethDamodharan - You have to have an initial spring context in any case. Anyway, I edited my answer and added the right annotation to use when configuring with configuration class and not with XML. But still in a standalone app you need to programatically load the context somehow in order for the annotations to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Avi. i found this AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ( RootConfig.class ); to enable the annotation . In Root configuration i defined all required bean its working like a charm for standalone java app with Spring :) :) #Thanks